# jquery $.each() and array validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement, each

I have a very simple code, but for some reason the last part is not working properly, Y have an array with some data

```
var dArray = {
    'var1': $("#var1").val(),
    'var2': $("#var2").val(),
    'var3': $("#var3").val(),
    'var4': $("#var4").val(),
    'var5': $("#var5").val(),
    'var6': $("#var6").val(),
    'var7': $("#var7").val(),
    'var8': $("#var8").val()
};
```

And to make sure every input have data in it I try to make a function that validate this (again a very simple one)

```
function valDataArray(nomArray) {
    $.each(nomArray, function (index, value) {
        if (value == "") {
            alert("must enter: " + index);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

The general idea is that the last function will send me a true or false so I can continue with my code, but for some reason it gives me "undefined" in every case.

Comment: You are not `return`ing anything from `valDataArray`. Note that `$.each` returns the array it iterated over, not the result of the callback.

Comment: you're right, I just fix the code with the help here, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Just add some flag to show if validation was successful or not

```
 function valDataArray(nomArray) {
    var valid = true;
    $.each(nomArray, function (index, value) {
        if (value == "") {
            valid = false;
            alert("must enter: " + index);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return valid;
}
```

Also, just from simplicity standpoint, you can simplify your code adding attribute:

first add attribute `data-required='true'` to each input

```
 <input type='text' id='var1' data-required='true' />
```

then got those which required

```
 function valDataArray(nomArray) {
    var valid = true;
    $('[data-required]').each(function (index, value) {
        if (value == "") {
            valid = false;
            alert("must enter: " + index);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: You should remove `return false;` and `return true;` from inside the loop. Also, `else` is not required.

Comment: @ataravati answered on your question, it can be valid to keep it if failing on first invalid field is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
function valDataArray(nomArray){
    var isValid = true;

    $.each(nomArray, function(index, value){
        if( value == ""){
            alert("must enter: " + index);
            isValid = false;
        }

    });

    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: that was funny. and 6 secs difference

Comment: I know. You should remove `return false;` and `return true;` from inside the loop. Also, `else` is not required.

Comment: it make sense to keep return false as it make entire set invalid and you don't need to check remaining fields.

Comment: You were completely right, thank you very much for the help, that fix the code

Answer (score 1):

Returning false inside the callback for an `$.each` loop will not exit the outer function, it will just end the loop.

Also, you don't want to exit from the function in the `else` case, as that would make the loop always end after the first item in the "array", and don't validate any more items.

Put the value that you want to return from the function in a variable inside the loop, and return it after the loop:

```
function valDataArray(nomArray){
  var ok = true;
  $.each(nomArray, function(index, value){
    if( value == ""){
        alert("must enter: " + index);
        ok = false;
        return false; // exit from loop
    }   
  });
  return ok;
}
```

Comment: you're right, thanks for the hel, I was able to fix the code :)